Firebase Authentication with Realtime DB not working on C#
im doing an C# app with .NET Windows Forms Framework and i have a permission dennied error when i try to send information to realtime db, but im have logged in in the app. The security of my Firebase Realtime DB is the following:
{
  "rules":{
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}

im using FirebaseAuthentication.net (v3.7.1) and FirebaseDatabase.net (v4.2.0) from Step Up Labs
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Database.Query;
using Firebase.Auth;

the code where the Permission Dennied Errors ocurred is the following
private async void button_reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("my_api_key"));


    var authResult = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("a mail that exists on firebase auth", "the correct password");


    if (authResult != null)
    {
        var user = new Users()
        {
            Address = "Country",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Name = "John"
        };

        var client = getFirebaseClient();

        await client.Child(nameof(Users))
            .PostAsync(user);
    }    
}

private FirebaseClient getFirebaseClient()
{
    return new FirebaseClient("my_database_url");
}

class users is
 public class Users
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
 }

the code passes authResult!=null, but then in this line await client.Child(nameof(Users)).PostAsync(user); the following error occurs
Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: 'Exception occured while processing the request.
Url: https://project-projectNumber-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Users/-NwVBBRKfhiWk5R1ISC5/.json?print=silent
Request Data: {"Name":"John","LastName":"Doe","Key":null,"Address":"Country"}
Response: {
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
'

i dont understand where the problem is, i hope someone have the answer

From reading the documentation on authenticating the StepUp Labs database client, you have to explicitly pass the auth information to FirebaseClient.
While you are signing the user in, you don't seem to be passing the auth information to the FirebaseClient anywhere. This seems relevant: Firebase authentication with email/password as do the first few code samples in this blog post Firebase Authentication C# Library.
